# Fetch Single asset without for loop?

Tags: assets, forloop

I've got a Assets field which is limited to 1 asset inside a Matrix field. Is there a better way to fetch the image without using a forloop?

At the minute I've got:

```twig
{% for image in block.backgroundImage %}
    {{ image.getUrl() }}
{% endfor %}
```

But it just doesn't seem right using a forloop when I know there is only one image.

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can call the [`first()`](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/elementcriteriamodel#first) function to just get the first image:

```twig
{% set image = block.backgroundImage.first() %}
{{ image.getUrl() }}
```

But this will fail if there is no image. So to be safe, you need:

```twig
{% set image = block.backgroundImage.first() %}
{% if image %}
    {{ image.getUrl() }}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: You could always use an inline conditional to get it down to one line, just for fun...: `{% block.backgroundImage | length ? block.backgroundImage.first().getUrl() : '' %}` :D

Answer (score 2):

Looking for the exact same answer I came across this question and would argue that joshangell's answer is the best if trying to simplify down from a for loop to one line of code.  The only issue is that the answer uses incorrect wrapping tags for an inline if statement.  So I submit this as the best answer for simplification and correct syntax:

```
{{ block.backgroundImage | length ? block.backgroundImage.first().getUrl() : '' }}
```

Just used it in my own project and it worked like a charm.

Comment: Another idea to get it down to one line would be to wrap it into a [macro](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/macro.html). Then you can easily add things like retina versions or common CSS classes to the HTML output and still have a clean template code in one line.